# Задача на рекурсию в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Задача

> Напишите функцию countChar(str, char) : array, которая будет считать
>   количество символов char в строке str и в каждом отдельном слове
>   строки. Возвращаемое значение – массив, первый элемент которого кол-во
>   символов в строке, а дальнейшие элементы – кол-во символов в каждом
>   слове. Если в слове символа нет, то выводить 0. Пример, строка
>   “Реализуйте функцию с применением рекурсии”, символ “и”, результат [6,
>   1, 1, 0, 2, 2]. Использовать стандартные методы для строк и массивов.

Как рекурсивно подсчитать количество нужных символов?

Comment: А зачем тут рекурсия?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно постараться, чтобы как-то искусственно ввести рекурию туда, где она не нужна)

Ну можно так, например (Если match нельзя, можно сделать через цикл и indexOf):

```js
let str = "Реализуйте функцию с применением рекурсии";

console.log( countChar(str, 'и') );

function countChar(str, char, arr) {
  let space = str.indexOf(" "); // Находит индекс первого пробела 
  // Или возвращает -1, если его нет.
  let reg = new RegExp( char , "g" ); // См. "регулярные выражения".
  arr = arr || [ (str.match(reg) || "").length ]; 
  // Первым элементом сразу будет кол-во всех совпадений
  
  if( space == -1 ){
    arr.push( (str.match(reg) || "").length );
    // Если match вернет null, получится ошибка "cannot read length of null"
    // Добавлено ИЛИ || "" 
    // Если первое выражение будет null, возьмется второе. А его length == 0;
    return arr;
  }
  
  arr.push( (str.slice(0, space).match(reg) || "").length );
  return countChar(str.slice( space + 1 ), char, arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так.

```js
var count = countChar('Реализуйте функцию с применением рекурсии', 'и');
console.log(count);

function countChar(str, char){
 
 // проверяем тип аргументов
 if((typeof str !== 'string') || (typeof char !== 'string')){
  return false;
 }
 
 var words = str.split(' '); // делим фразу на слова
 
 // если одно слово то считаем кол-во нужных символов в нем и возвращаем результат
 if(words.length === 1){
  var count = 0;
  var word = words[0];
  var lastpos = 0;
  while((lastpos = word.indexOf(char, lastpos)) !== -1){
   lastpos++; // поиск следующего символа начинаем на позицию дальше после найденного
   count++;
  }
  return count;
  
 // если слов несколько передаем каждое слово в данную функцию и записываем результат в массив
 } else if (words.length > 1) {
  var countArr = [0];
  words.forEach(function(word){
   var count = countChar(word, char);
   if(typeof count !== 'number') return;
   countArr[0] += count;
   countArr.push(count);
  });
  return countArr;
  
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```